# Can we set single Database for two different IBM BPM Std 8.5.7 environment?

Tags: ibm-bpm

We want to setup DR server for IBM BPM Std 8.5.7 and planning to use Prod DB (Oracle) so that if for some reason Prod BPM environment becomes unavailable we can use Prod DB data in DR IBM BPM. Is this possible? What factors need to considered for this?

At present we take the snapshot of Prod DB and using this DB snapshot for COB, all servers are started but when we open Process Admin console we don't see the "Installed App" option and menus on left side to manage users. It seems DR BPM admin ID does not have required roles to get the details.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd like to point you to the article below;

[Disaster recovery guidance for IBM Business Process Manager](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/bpm/library/techarticles/1504_richardson/1504_richardson.html)

Please note the difference between *configuration* data and *runtime* data as defined on this article. Since some configuration data resides at profile folders of your servers, not the database, it's not enough to just move a snapshot of production database to DR. You must also synchronise configuration data on your file system. This is probably why you can't use your DR BPM as you expected, you move runtime data to DR, but you're missing configuration data.

As for your question on what configurations are possible and what factors to consider, unfortunately answer is not so simple, as you have many alternatives.

Article above highlights which factors to consider for your DR design. There are seven different alternatives for DR topology. These evaluated according to abovementioned factors, and advantages/disadvantages are explained. You must choose one of these according to your specific requirements and resource availability.

Comment: The linked article by Chris Richardson is the current standard for disaster recovery (DR) topology implementations. Following that guide will lead you to create a DR for your scenario.